# Migration from Nexus single context to tenant configuration

Tags: cisco, migration

It is my task to barge in to a Nexus 7K system that was configured for a single company and carve out resources for my separate company so that we may make use of the resources at this site.

I'm very familiar with 6500 IOS, but haven't found a whole lot of material on how to move a config into from the root context to a new VDC. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Or should I plan to pony up and hire a Nexus guru?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So there are a lot of variables that may apply here.  First off, I'd absolutely recommend that you check out the [Nexus 7K VDC Configuration Guide](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/datacenter/sw/nx-os/virtual_device_context/configuration/guide/b-7k-Cisco-Nexus-7000-Series-NX-OS-Virtual-Device-Context-Configuration-Guide.html) if you haven't already, as it's a good comprehensive treatment of the subject.

To your immediate questions, though - it's important to understand that there isn't really a *root* context.  Everything currently on the box is in a VDC - specifically VDC 1.  If you set up a new VDC (..say VDC 2) and move interfaces into it then you can pretty much just start configuring.  The only situation in which you'd need to materially change the existing configuration would be if you needed to move connections around to open up port groups on an ASIC boundary.

This last point (ASIC boundaries) is one of the big items that needs to be tracked.  Different LC's have varying numbers of ports and a varying number of those ports will map to a given ASIC.  The ASIC itself is mapped to a VDC - so if one port on that ASIC goes to a given VDC then the rest will need to go as well.  As an example - the original (now EOS/EOL) 32-port 10GE blades for the 7K could be broken up into 4 groups of 8 ports - so 4 VDC's.  The 24-port 10GE M2 blade can be allocated on a per-port basis, etc.

By the same token mixing different types of line cards within a VDC has a substantial number of caveats.  The M1 blades mentioned above can be mixed with M2's or F2e's but not both at the same time (so M1+M2 or M1+F2e are both OK, but not M1+M2+F2e).  There are also implications to capabilities and throughput - so, again, M1+F2e pushes all L3 forwarding to the M1 blades (..even though the F2e is faster by itself) and drops buffer sizes and other capabilities to a least common denominator.  As a  general statement if you can avoid mixing LC types within a VDC your life will be simpler.

This may be less of an issue for you but another concern is allocating resources to VDC's.  You can control the amount of CPU and memory, the number of routes and VLAN's, etc for each VDC.

From an administrative point of view you might also need to track on who holds privileges to adjust VDC's or reboot the entire box vs those who have full configuration rights *within* a given VDC.

Finally - how modern is the box itself?  Supervisor 1, 2 or 2e?  Fabric 1 or 2?  Sup2/2e potentially allow for up to 8 VDC's while the sup1 supports a max of 4.  The Sup2/2e is needed to move beyond NXOS 6.2 and if you have a Sup1 you need to get to 8G of DRAM to even run 6.2.  There also may be a need for additional licenses to support VDC operations.

Anyhow, take a look at the guide linked above - it should get you started.